# Adverb location according to auxiliary verb

Tags: adverbs, auxiliary-verbs, adverb-position

Even though there are examples of location of adverb related to auxiliary verb, I am still doubtful about where to put the adverb in this particular example. I need to make a very formal sentence:

> A good prevention knowledge in a society **can** **significantly** reduce contagious diseases.
>
> A good prevention knowledge in a society **can** reduce contagious diseases **significantly**.

Answer (score 1):

These are both equally grammatical, and identical in meaning; either would be acceptable in a formal situation.

The only thing I would suggest is changing "prevention knowledge" to **knowledge of prevention**.